# ansible playbook with host group running - No host matched

Tags: linux, ansible, virtual-machine, ansible-inventory

When I perform

```
ansible -i /home/linux/ansible/my-prereqs/hosts  -m ping 'test'


172.16.57.101 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false, 
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

my host inventory file is located in **`/home/linux/ansible/my-prereqs/hosts`**

my inventory file is like below

```
[ansible-vm]
172.16.57.102

**[test]**
172.16.57.101
```

Now I want to run a play book but I am not able to run them by inventory groups

```
ansible-playbook  -i /home/linux/ansible/my-prereqs/hosts  -l test my-prereqs.yaml 

but I get the following 


PLAY ***************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
```

What am I missing here for my arguments ?

Comment: What is the `hosts` directive in your playbook?

Comment: Perfect  just figured out with your pointers ...It was different from the inventory file group name its working Thanks @KonstantinSuvorov

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

> What is the hosts directive in your playbook?

...

> It was different from the inventory file group name